# Changing gloabal pandas dataframe values inplace through a function in a class by a tkinter button

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I have  a class called `mclass` which is supposed to be used as a tkinter object in the main program. Inside this class, I have a few tkinter buttons and one of them should be able to edit a pandas dataframe and make the changes inplace globally.

Here is the code, the function of interest is `self.save_data()` and the pandas dataframe `table_cat` is supposed to be edited by the button `self.saving`. I have tried a lot of different thing but the changes wont happen inplace in the original dataframe for some reason.

```
#some pandas dataframe with 10000 rows .. the column structure is given below
table_cat=pd.DataFrame(columns=['index','redshifted_freq','source_found','velocity_d','velocity_u'])
class mclass:
    def __init__(self,  window=None, mclass_df=None):
        self.saving = Button(window,text='Save',bg='red',command=self.save_data)
        self.saving.pack(side='bottom')
       

    def save_data (self):
        i=self.e4.get()
        self.data_frame.loc['source_found',i]=self.e.get()            # e-> tkinter button for 'source found'
        self.data_frame.loc['redshifted_freq',i]=float(self.e1.get()) # e1-> tkinter button for 'redshifted_frec' 
        self.data_frame.loc['velocity_d',i]=float(self.e2.get())      # e2-> tkinter button for 'velocity_d'
        self.data_frame.loc['velocity_u',i]=float(self.e3.get())      # e3-> tkinter button for 'velocity_u'
        global table_cat
        table_cat=self.data_frame
```

Answer (score 0):

This line `table_cat=self.data_frame` overwrites the previous content of your global dataframe, so every time you click that button your previous data is lost.

You actually need to append the new data, like:

```
table_cat = table_cat.append(self.data_frame)
```

Comment: But that's the thing, i want it to be overwritten , i want the changes to happen in 'table_cat'... But after assignment , table_cat remains unchanged

Comment: Could you then share the rest of your code? Because we need to know where and how you are accessing `table_cat` data